# Eclipse Indigo is unable to read repository (update sites)

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-indigo

First of all this question has been asked at least twice.

I tried several approaches with no effect.

Here's the problem:

When I try to download/update plugins like EclEmma, Eclipse starts to communicate with the repository and that takes about 5 minutes. After that I get an error:

"An error occured while collecting items to be installed
 session context was:(...)

Unable to read repository at http: (...)
 Read time out

(... for every *.jar)"

What I was trying to fix the problem was running eclipse as an admin (got vista x86 running) and changing the connection properties from native to direct and back. I also tried deleting saved repositories and adding again. No effect at all.

I have no proxy configured and don't need one.

This is getting kind of personal between me and my IDE :D

So I hope you guys can help me out.

Answer (score 19):

Thanks Zoltán (köszi :D), but i found the error last night.

**Resolution**

After hours of debugging I figured out that **AVG Anti-Virus** Software blocks the request. After deactivating it for temporarily, Eclipse installed the new software.

Comment: Thanks for posting this.  This has been driving me crazy for the past few nights, and it was caused by AVG for me too.

Comment: Just wanted to add exactly what should be disabled in AVG: in the `Link Scanner` component, the `Active Surf-Shield` should be disabled.

Answer (score 4):

In my case timeout was caused by definition of SOCKS proxy... we have proxy.company.com:80 and I incorrectly provided that proxy to all three (HTTP, HTTPS and SOCKS) connection schemas. Removal of proxy from SOCKS resolved the problem

Answer (score 2):

Try to open the internal web browser of Eclipse (Window menu/Show view/Other...), and navigate to the 1) update site url, and 2) to any webpage.

If the latter one is not working, then Eclipse does not have connection to the internet, and you should try to open a new workspace, and try installing from there (possibly something wrong in the workspace settings).

If the second one works, but the first one does not, that suggests that the update site is not working. In this case report to the developers.

Answer (score 2):

I also had this problem (my system: Win7, jdk7, Eclipse Indigo).

I installed jre6, changed my JAVA_HOME, ran eclipse with the following:

```
eclipse -debug -consolelog -vm 'c:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\java.exe'
```

Install the plugins/updates, then switch back to using jdk7.

Worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

Temporarily disabling AVG firewall fixed the issue for me.

Eclipse then installed the Android plugin.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, adding these lines to eclipse.ini solved the problem

```
-vmargs (this one was alreayd there)
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```